# Hibernate - Null foreign key when trying to do an insert

Tags: java, hibernate, null, foreign-keys

When I'm doing an insert, the foreign key in traduction (idMot references mot) is null where as my front send the correct foreign key. I end up with this error : ***not-null property references a null or transient value : com.virtual.expertise.mydico.model.Traduction.mot***

I suppose that I'm doing something wrong in my models but still don't know what.

**Here is the traduction model:**

```
      @Id
            @Column(name = "id")
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            private Long id;

            @Column(name = "langue")
            private String langue;

            @Column(name = "traduction")
            private String traduction;

            @JsonBackReference(value = "mot-traduction")
            @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
            @JoinColumn(name = "idMot", nullable = false, insertable = true, 


updatable = false)
        private Mot mot;

        @CreationTimestamp
        @Column(name = "dateCreation")
        private Date dateCreation;
```

**Here is the mot model:**

```
@Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "libelle")
    private String libelle;

    @JsonBackReference(value = "user-mot")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "idUser", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false)
    private User user;

    /** les traductions. */
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "mot-traduction")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mot", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Traduction> traductions;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "dateCreation")
    private Date dateCreation;
```

**Here is the traduction table:**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `traduction`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `traduction` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `langue` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `traduction` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idMot` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dateCreation` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idMot_idx` (`idMot`),
  CONSTRAINT `idMot` FOREIGN KEY (`idMot`) REFERENCES `mot` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

**Here is my webService:** (where in traduction idMot appears as null)

```
@POST
    @Path("/create")
    public Traduction createTraduction(Traduction traduction) throws Exception {
        return FacadeBackOffice.getInstance().getTraductionService().createTraduction(traduction);
    }
```

May someone has a solution?

Comment: Did you assign an instance to `Traduction.mot` that is not persisted (has no ID yet) ? Try to persist it first.

Comment: If `Mot` hadn't been persisted before `Traduction` `Mot.id` would still be null. But in this case hibernate normally throws an exception with message "detached entity passed to persist". Maybe something with `GenerationType.AUTO` is not working properly. Which database and dialect are you using?

Comment: I'm using mySQL workbench...

Comment: I don't see in the code where do you set mot: traduction.setMot(mot);

Answer (score 0):

Use cascade type all in your many to one mapping as well.

```
 @Id
            @Column(name = "id")
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            private Long id;

            @Column(name = "langue")
            private String langue;

            @Column(name = "traduction")
            private String traduction;

            @JsonBackReference(value = "mot-traduction")
            @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
            @JoinColumn(name = "idMot", nullable = false, insertable = true, 


updatable = false)
        private Mot mot;

        @CreationTimestamp
        @Column(name = "dateCreation")
        private Date dateCreation;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!!! I tryied your solution but i still got the same result...